# Django OneToManyField ProfileUpdate integration with user registration

Tags: python, django

I m having problems integrating user registration form info with another form used as a profile updater
Models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
skill_choices = (('Beginner', 'BEGINNER'),
                 ('Intermediate', 'INTERMEDIATE'),
                 ('Expert', 'EXPERT'))

user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
assumed_technical_ski_level = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=skill_choices)
years_of_experience = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
money_to_spend = models.IntegerField(blank=True)


@receiver(post_save, sender= user)
def create_user_profile(self, sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=user)
def save_user_profile(self, sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

Views.py

```
class ProfileUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
profile_form = ProfileForm
template_name = 'aplicatie2/profile-update.html'

def post(self, request):
    post_data = request.POST or None

    profile_form = ProfileForm(post_data, instance = request.user.profile)
    if profile_form.is_valid():
        profile_form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('aplicatie2:lista'))
    context = self.get_context_data(profile_form = profile_form)

    return self.render_to_response(context)

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return self.post(request)
```

Forms.py

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Profile
    fields = ('location', 'assumed_technical_ski_level', 'years_of_experience',
              'money_to_spend')
```

The registration is done using the django standard library UserCreationForm
I'm getting this error :

> RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /companies/questions/
>  User has no
> profile.

Does someone know a solution to this ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably `save_user_profile` is called before `create_user_profile`. Remove the `save_user_profile` signal, `Profile.objects.create` (also the form) already save the `Profile` instance, so there is no need to call `save`. Also change the sender of the signal (`User` and not `user`):

**signals**

```py
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(self, sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

Comment: Still the same error

Comment: @TibiGhimbas Did you remove the `save_user_profile` signal from your code? Did you get this error in your signup view?

Comment: yes and it is still giving me the same error, and looking into the traceback for the error it stops at this  "profile_form = ProfileForm(post_data, instance = request.user.profile)" from views.py

Comment: @TibiGhimbas Try to create a new user and test the view with that. If the error does not occur maybe is because you have created your old instances when the signal does not work properly, in that case run the this in the shell:  `for user in User.objects.all(): if not hasattr(user, 'profile'): Profile.objects.create(user=user)` that manually creates `Profile` instances. Did your signal is called (try to put a print statement during tests)?